# TSQL Two different tables, 800GB vs 2GB Find common

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, generatedblock table, and addresses table
The generatedblock  table has a column called expandedblock block.
The addresses table has a column called address.
What I need to do is find if in the generatedblock table there is a value in the addresses table.
I have tried failed code but I am not reposting because my tsql sucks,
How do I check every row in the address table, or visi versa contains a value, and to list the value in a temp table.

```
table generatedblock column expandedblock
-------------
1234
2334
4567
9878
4353
2345
3456

table addresses column address
-------------
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
6666
1234
```

i get result return more than 1 row and I want those rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM generatedblock
WHERE ExpandedBlock in (SELECT DISTINCT address FROM addresses)
```

Comment: Post some sample data. Also, what's the actual issue - you don't know how to write the query or can't write it in efficient way?

Comment: Both @gotqn Done I gave an example

Comment: Are the tables data changed constantly? Are the tables read constantly? If yes - maybe it will be better to perform batch update and then create a trigger to precalc the values.

Comment: the tables are indexed, and the results are needed on a one time basis, I added my code but it's not showing the rows from the generatedblock table, it tells me more then 1 row ... @gotqn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM generatedblock A
INNER JOIN address  B
    ON A.ExpandedBlock = B.address;
```

Comment: That took 14 hours on a mysql, 8 core i7 7700  16 gig mem..... ssd raid 0 , your trigger comment is starting to look good.

Comment: @user1264626 You said you are doing this one time, right? If not, it will be better to apply another approach.

Comment: Well I have a script that takes addresses, (so far it has yet to complete after 4 days, I have partial, but not full, ) I am expecting 15 days, to receive the complete list of true addresses, I am not truly concerned over the 100- 2000 address I might miss over that time, but this script needs to run, on at the moment 64GB of compressed MySQL data. I am hoping that I can grow this data to 2TB, but it looks like it is going to take time generating the core dataset. I have 24 cores working on it at 3 GHZ, and I am generating about 2GB per day.Nothing that I want FASTER. but that's not this topic